# Why do browsers parse hex entries of an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I was researching about XSS attacks and then I've found that we can XSS someone with this string that does not involves the characters `<` or `>`, however it still Works:

```
%3Cscript%3Dalert(XSS%20Example)%3C%2Fscript%3E
```

This leads me to think that the browser understand the string above as the same as

```
<script>alert...
```

So the browser HTML parser is understanding the entry `%3C` as the `<` character, for example. Why does the browser do this? Is there another way to represent the character `<` that still could be used to XSS? How do I know, for sure, that some entry will not be evaluated as `<` or `>`? Where can I read about the diferente ways to represent symbols in HTML, that will be accepted by a browser HTML parser?

Comment: Have a look at 'URL encoding / decoding'. This link may be useful: [lot about Url encoding](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm). Also: [Try it yourself](http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php)

Comment: In what context is the [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encode) string being used to cause XSS? It will be decoded when placed where URLs are expected, e.g. `href` attributes, but the decoded form shouldn't then be parsed as markup.

Comment: I saw this example here: http://www.blackhatlibrary.net/XSS so it does not have to do with the URL but with the HTML

Comment: @user3600110 The examples in that page refer to both URL and HTML. The values are being sent in the request to the server-side script, URL-encoded either within the query-string or POST body, and are output unsanitized as markup in the response.

Comment: `I've found that we can XSS someone`, a bit of a broad statement. How are we going to XSS someone in this case? What's the context of the attack?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski so where exactly they're converted to < and >? Is in in the http?

Comment: @user3600110 Server-side as part of the parameter parsing. Since the examples involve PHP (`xss.php`), that would be during the filling of `$_GET` and/or `$_POST`. "[***Note**:
The GET variables are passed through `urldecode()`.*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php#refsect1-reserved.variables.get-notes)"